# Using strcpy() in C, difference between stack and heap?

Tags: c, string, heap-memory, stack-memory

I met a problem when using strcpy() of libc, here is the code:

```
 16 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 17 {    
 18     char* src = "0123456789";
 19     char* des = (char*) malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
 20      
 21     des = strcpy(des, src);                                                                                                                          
 22     des = strcpy(src, "1010101");
 23      
 24     printf("%s\n", des);
 25     return 0;
 26 }
```

I want to check if strcpy works well when its destination string is in stack or in heap, so you will see line 21, and line 22.

It turns out that, line 21 works good, but the program will throw a SEGMENTATION FAULT when it goes to line 22. And what's more, I've debug into libc, and I find that it crashes at this line:

```
91         while ((*dest++ = *src++) != '\0')
```

It is not very clear to see at which point it crush, so I have split this one statement into several and make them have the same function with line 91. I will omit that piece of code here, and at last it crashes at the assignment for *dest.

So here I cannot understand why it crashes. At line 22, ***src*** is a address as well, the only thing that is different from ***des*** of line 21 is stack and heap. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: You tried to write to a string literal. They are neither stack nor heap, they are not writable.

Comment: `src is a address as well, the only thing it diff from des of line 21 is stack and heap` no, that's not true.

Comment: When are compiler vendors going to stop this?  `char *src = "123456";` assigns a const char array address to a non const pointer.  We've had more than 20 years to fix old programs, and at worst a compiler option could override the default and allow this sloppiness.

Comment: Posting code with line numbers is not well received, it prevents easy cut and paste into a source file for testing.  Please avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> At line 22, src is a address as well, the only thing it diff from des of line 21 is stack and heap.

The C standard doesn't exactly specify where string literals are allocated (it doesn't care much about details of the machine), but there's no reason to assume it will be on the stack when sharing a single global object in static space (the third main allocation area, that you've forgotten about) would work just as well.

Look at your code more closely:

```
char* src = "0123456789";
```

`src` is a single pointer variable located on the stack. But you've filled that pointer with the address of another object, and the string literal could be anywhere because the compiler would be a fool to re-allocate it every time the function is called.

If you did this:

```
char src[] = "0123456789";
```

The different syntax on `src` says you want it to be an array, not a pointer to an array elsewhere. *Now* a string will be allocated on the stack, and populated with data *from* the literal `"0123456789"`, but will not be the same object as it. You can write to this version of `src` no problem, because it actually does allocate and fill a new array every time, since you've explicitly asked it to do so.

Comment: Thanks, your code works well, and it makes me think of something called data segment(.data) if I am right. So is my code crush because writing data of .data?

Comment: That's beyond the scope of C as a language and into the realm of what your compiler chooses to do. All the language says is not to write to string literals. It's widely considered a longstanding "bug" in the language definition that they have element type `char` instead of `const char` (this is a difference from C++).